# Powershell script to set new DNS settings in Windows 7 and Windows 10 with one script

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, windows-7-x64

Need help with creating a single powershell script that will work with Windows 7 (powershell 2.0) and Windows 10 (powershell 5.0) so that i can be pushed via GPO. *we have no domain DHCP was we are getting IP leases from MPLS router...

So far i have accomplished the following with a batch file for windows 7 (non-powershell)

```
@ECHO OFF

set vardns1=1.1.1.1
set vardns2=2.2.2.2


ECHO Setting Primary DNS
netsh int ip set dns name = "Local Area Connection" source = static addr = %vardns1%

ECHO Setting Secondary DNS
netsh int ip add dns name = "Local Area Connection" addr = %vardns2%

ECHO Flushing DNS
ipconfig /flushdns

ECHO Registering New DNS settings
ipconfig /registerdns
```

And this code for Windows 10 (powershell 5.0)

```
If (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent
()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]"Administrator")) {
                Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs
                Exit
            }
    #The servers that we want to use
    $newDNSServers = "1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2"

    # Get all network adapters that already have DNS servers set
    $adapters = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object {$_.DNSServerSearchOrder -ne $null}

    # Set the DNS server search order for all of the previously-found adapters
    $adapters | ForEach-Object {$_.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($newDNSServers)}

    #Flushing DNS
    ipconfig /flushdns

    #Registering DNS
    ipconfig /registerdns

    Set-DnsClientGlobalSetting -SuffixSearchList @("mydomain.local")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build two scripts and use WMI filtering on the GPO to run one on W10 and another on W7 systems. Easier than trying to make a polymorphic script.

Answer (score 0):

Why can you not run the Windows 10 powershell script on your Windows 7 machines?

You are setting the DNS addresses with WMI there should be no problem.

Can you try running it locally on a windows 7 machine and share the error?

If your using powershell via GPO it can be nice to write errors to a log file.

even something basic like this at the end of your script

```
if($Error)
{
    Export-Clixml -Path C:\GPOError.xml
}
```

This will save the whole error object(s)
You can import it back into powershell and view it using

Import-Clixml